# Why are kernel methods with RBFs effective for handwritten digits (letters) classification?

Tags: classification, svm, gaussian-process

The question emerged while reading Ch. 3 of [Rasmussen & Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/) . In the end of this chapter, the authors gave results for the problem of handwritten digits classification (16x16 greyscale pictures); features are 256 pixel intensities + bias. I was surprised that in such a high-dimensional problem, 'metric' methods, like Gaussian processes with squared exponential kernel, or SVM with the same kernel, behave quite nice without any dimension reduction preceeded.

Also, I heard sometimes that SVM is good for [essentially bag-of-word] text classification. Why aren't they suffering from the curse of dimensionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put this interesting discussion on the ground, one can modify the toy script from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_digits_classification.html to get some simple statistics.

For example, let us look at the last test vector, and how far it is from 519 support vectors (the space has 8*6=42 dimensions).

Distances are big enough, laying in the interval [26.7394839142 64.88451279]. However, gamma is small (0.001), i.e. variance is big so "effective distance" is small (and that is the key, I think!).

As a consequence, scalar product (i.e. exp(-gamma*|test-support|^2) with all 519 support vectors lays in the interval [0.937175688934 0.973614850818]

Comment: Welcome to the site, @simonkarp. Is this intended as an *answer* to the OP's question, or to assist in making the question more easily answerable? Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. If this is an answer, can you clarify how it answers the question? Since you're new here, you may want to read our [about page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains information for new users.

Comment: @gung In fact, for me it clarifies things a lot :)

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @ostrodmit. I honestly couldn't tell if this was an answer (but then I don't know this topic). If it does resolve your issue, you might want to accept it by clicking the check mark to its left below the vote total.

Comment: @simonkarp, it is interesting to look at that from the view of hyperparameter selection. why is this not the case where it performs poor?

Answer (score 0):

From a machine learning perspective, 257 dimensions is far from high dimensional. A wide range of problems, including text classification, are solved in thousands of dimensions. Currently, problems that are considered high dimensional are in millions of dimensions.

Both Gaussian processes and SVMs are part of a larger class of algorithms called [kernel methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_methods). The combination of the [kernel trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_trick), the [representer theorem](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/281b-sp08/8.pdf) and proper use of [regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29) make these methods robust against the curse of dimensionality.

Kernel methods always work on distances between points, regardless of the dimensionality in which this distance is defined. The dimensionality can be infinite, for example with the Gaussian kernel (see e.g. slide 11 of [this presentation by Chih-Jen Lin](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/kuleuven_svm.pdf)).

From the representer theorem we know that the solution of any kernel method can be written in terms of instances, and is therefore limited in dimensionality and complexity.

Comment: Marc, 
many thanks for an answer, but it doesn't adress the issue I am troubled with. In fact, wouldn't even in 250 dimensions, rather than in 10^6, the result of calculating RBF a nonesence? I know that with kernel trick we can inherently project data in a high-dimensional space in the same time NOT suffering from the curse of dimensionality (simply becase the kernel function is formulated in the initial low-dimensional space). But what if the initial space is, say, even 100-dimensional? The euclidean distance, which is in RBF, is completely uninformative even in 7-8 dimensions.

Comment: @ostrodmit `The euclidean distance, which is in RBF, is completely uninformative even in 7-8 dimensions.` On what do you base this assertion?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality -> Distance functions together with the fact that negative squared distance is under the exponent

Comment: Did you read the regularization link I posted? Here's another one ... http://www.info.ucl.ac.be/~pdupont/pdupont/pdf/Capacity_n4.pdf

Comment: I read it before, but as far as I can see it does not answer my question. Now I have 2 ideas why RBFs would perform well in this problem: 1) intrinsic dimension of data is very small; 2) maybe hyperparameter optimization helps (sigma in the denominator under the exponent). (2) is in fact mentioned (for svm) in simonkarp's answer